# "TS2339: Property 'XX' does not exist on type 'Vue'" when bundling with rollup

Tags: typescript, vue.js, rollup

I have a Vue/TypeScript class that calls a public method on another Vue/TypeScript class. It compiles and runs fine with tsc or WebPack. But when compiling with rollup and the rollup-plugin-vue, I get an error that `Property 'close' does not exist on type 'Vue'.`

Repro link: https://repl.it/@orobert91/PropertyDoesNotExistOnTypeVue

Popover.vue:

```
import { Component } from "vue-property-decorator";
import Vue from "vue";

@Component
export default class Popover extends Vue {
    public close() {
        this.isShown = false;
    }
}
```

DatePicker.vue:

```
import Popover from "components/commonControls/Popover.vue";
import { Component } from "vue-property-decorator";
import Vue from "vue";

@Component
export default class DatePicker extends Vue {

    public $refs!: {
        popover: Popover
    }

    public get myMethod() {
        this.$refs.popover.close(); //COMPILATION ERROR HERE
    }
}
```

tsconfig.json configuration file:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "module": "es6",
        "target": "es6",
        "jsx": "react",
        "jsxFactory": "h",
        "strict": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "declaration": true,
        "declarationDir": "./dist",
        "baseUrl": "./src",
        "outDir": "./dist",
        "plugins": [
            { "transform": "typescript-transform-paths" },
            { "transform": "typescript-transform-paths", "afterDeclarations": true }
        ]
    },
    "include": [
        "src/**/*"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "dist"
    ]
}
```

rollup.config.js configuration file:

```
import vue from 'rollup-plugin-vue';
import resolve from 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve';
import cleaner from 'rollup-plugin-cleaner';
import copy from 'rollup-plugin-copy';
import ttypescript from 'ttypescript'
import tsPlugin from 'rollup-plugin-typescript2'

export default {
    input: 'src/index.ts',
    output: {
        format: 'esm',
        file: 'dist/index.js'
    },
    external: ['vue'],
    plugins: [
        resolve(),
        tsPlugin({
            typescript: ttypescript
        }),
        vue(),
        cleaner({
            targets: [
                './dist/'
            ]
        }),
        copy({
            targets: [
              { src: 'src/laravel-mix', dest: 'dist/' },
            ]
        })
    ]
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be having this issue because you didn't register the `Popover` component in your `Datepicker.vue` component

Also, another possible reason for the error could be that you are using this snippet below to tell typescript not to throw an error when using this.$refs.popover.

```js
 public $refs!: {
   popover: Popover
 }
```

Maybe instead of `this.popover.close()`, you meant to write `this.$refs.popover.close()`?

Try this

Datepicker.vue

```js
@Component({
  components: {
    Popover
  }
})
export default class DatePicker extends Vue {

    public $refs!: {
        popover: Popover
    }

    public get myMethod() {
        this.$refs.popover.close(); //using refs to access the DOM directly
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes I meant "this.$refs.popover.close()", that was a mistake in my post, I have updated the question accordingly with a full repro link. This is really a rollup bundling issue, as it compiles and works as expected when compiled with tsc or WebPack. The method is called and produces the expected result.